# transpose lines to columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, calc

I have a file with more than 2.5k lines like the following.

```
NAME    TYPE    A   B   C
JOHN    T1  10,00   19,00   65,00
JOHN    T2  11,00   23,00   64,00
JOHN    T3  12,00   33,00   34,00
JOHN    T4  13,00   34,00   32,00
PAUL    T1  14,00   43,00   23,00
PAUL    T2  15,00   90,00   34,00
PAUL    T3  16,00   32,00   56,00
PAUL    T4  20,00   45,00   65,00
RINGO   T1  25,00   60,00   87,00
RINGO   T2  24,00   30,00   23,00
RINGO   T3  31,00   20,00   54,00
RINGO   T4  75,00   10,00   12,00
GEORGE  T1  17,00   11,00   98,00
GEORGE  T2  65,00   12,00   47,00
GEORGE  T3  98,00   42,00   86,00
GEORGE  T4  32,00   43,00   37,00
```

I need to rearrange the data, so that each name will be shown in just ONE LINE. So the 4 types that originaly are shown in lines must be shown in new columns, like this:

```
NAME    A/T1    A/T2    A/T3    A/T4    B/T1    B/T2    B/T3    B/T4    C/T1    C/T2    C/T3    C/T4
JOHN    10,00   11,00   12,00   13,00   19,00   23,00   33,00   34,00   65,00   64,00   34,00   32,00
PAUL    14,00   15,00   16,00   20,00   43,00   90,00   32,00   45,00   23,00   34,00   56,00   65,00
RINGO   25,00   24,00   31,00   75,00   60,00   30,00   20,00   10,00   87,00   23,00   54,00   12,00
GEORGE  17,00   65,00   98,00   32,00   11,00   12,00   42,00   43,00   98,00   47,00   86,00   37,00
```

Any help will be apreciated....
Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: This is not an exact transpose.  Although it may be still duplicate the referenced question is different in format.

Comment: Just edited the question to try to explain that it's not a direct transpose. Have not found any similar solution that apply to the problem. I belieave it should not be marked as duplicate.